# "marker-mid" is not working with path d3.js force layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

How to append the "marker-mid" on the link (path svg) in the force layout.

Here is my code :

```
var path = d3.select('.pitch').selectAll("path")
            .data(force.links())
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .classed('g_path', true)
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "link").attr("marker-mid", function(d) {
            return "url(#BLUE)"
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  to your svg to create the element you want to be the marker and the class "box" to style the rect...

```
svg.append("defs")
 .append("marker")
 .attr("id", "BLUE")
 .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
 .attr("refX",  5 )
 .attr("refY", 5)
 .attr("markerWidth", 10)
 .attr("markerHeight", 10)
 .attr("orient", "auto")
 .attr("class","box")
 .append("rect")
 .style("width","5px")
 .style("height","5px")
```